Optimizing json.Marshal in Go
I have a service that needs to marshal large JSONs (~50KB length).
In the beginning, I used map[string]interface{} and encoded it but it consumed a lot of CPU. Then I tried to map the JSON into structs and encode the struct, but it didn't solve the issue.
I tried ffjson, easyjson but they didn't improve the situation.
Do you have any idea what I can do as an optimization?
The data to marshal:
type Struct1 struct {
  Attr14 []map[string]interface{} `json:"attr14,omitempty"`
  Attr15 string                   `json:"attr15,omitempty"`
  Attr16 map[string]string        `json:"attr16,omitempty"`
}

type Struct2 struct {
  Attr1  map[string]interface{}   `json:"attr1"`
  Attr2  map[string]interface{}   `json:"attr2"`
  Attr3  Struct1                  `json:"attr3"`
  Attr4  Struct1                  `json:"attr4"`
  Attr5  Struct1                  `json:"attr5"`
  Attr6  []interface{}            `json:"attr6"`
  Attr7  []map[string]interface{} `json:"attr7"`
  Attr8  map[string]interface{}   `json:"attr8"`
  Attr9  []map[string]interface{} `json:"attr9,omitempty"`
  Attr10 map[string]interface{}   `json:"attr10"`
  Attr11 map[string]interface{}   `json:"attr11"`
  Attr12 map[string]interface{}   `json:"attr12"`
  Attr13 []map[string]interface{} `json:"attr13"
}



It would be helpful to know what „a lot of CPU“ is, what you expect and how your data is structured.

It's possible that you can improve performance by changing how the data is represented or by writing a custom JSON encoder.  Edit the question to show the code that you tried and the structure of the data.

@CeriseLimón I updated my question with the structure of the struct I tried to marshal. I used encoding/json Marshal method.

Update: Thanks to @CeriseLimón for pointing out that I got it wrong initially and benchmarked the unmarshalling instead of the marshalling.


Premature optimization is the root of all evil.
Donald Knuth

Apparently, you have profiled just the encoding, of course encoding will take up a significant part of an encoding process.
So the question arises whether the JSON marshaling is objectively efficient.
I ran a little benchmark:
package gounmarshalperformance78772815

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

type unknownJSON map[string]interface{}

type testStruct struct {
    Name     string  `json:"name"`
    Language string  `json:"language"`
    ID       string  `json:"id"`
    Bio      string  `json:"bio"`
    Version  float64 `json:"version"`
}

func benchmark(path string, arraysize int, b *testing.B) {
    d, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    foo := make([]unknownJSON, arraysize)
    err = json.Unmarshal(d, &foo)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r, err := json.Marshal(foo)
        require.NoError(b, err)
        require.NotEmpty(b, r)
    }
}

func benchmarkStruct(path string, arraysize int, b *testing.B) {
    d, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    foo := make([]testStruct, arraysize)
    err = json.Unmarshal(d, &foo)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r, err := json.Marshal(foo)
        require.NoError(b, err)
        require.NotEmpty(b, r)
    }
}

func benchmarkEncoder(path string, arraysize int, b *testing.B) {
    d, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    foo := make([]unknownJSON, arraysize)
    err = json.Unmarshal(d, &foo)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, len(d)))
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
        err := enc.Encode(foo)
        require.NoError(b, err)
        buf.Reset()
    }
}

func Benchmark64kMapStringInterface(b *testing.B) {
    // Unmarshal the JSON data to determine the size of the array
    // Array sizes were determined by running the following command:
    // $ jq length testdata/78772815-{64k,128k,256k}.json
    benchmark("testdata/78772815-64k.json", 197, b)
}

func Benchmark128kMapStringInterface(b *testing.B) {
    benchmark("testdata/78772815-128k.json", 788, b)
}

func Benchmark256kMapStringInterface(b *testing.B) {
    benchmark("testdata/78772815-256k.json", 792, b)
}

func Benchmark64kStruct(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkStruct("testdata/78772815-64k.json", 197, b)
}

func Benchmark128kStruct(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkStruct("testdata/78772815-128k.json", 788, b)
}

func Benchmark256kStruct(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkStruct("testdata/78772815-256k.json", 792, b)
}

func Benchmark64kEncoder(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkEncoder("testdata/78772815-64k.json", 197, b)
}

func Benchmark128kEncoder(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkEncoder("testdata/78772815-128k.json", 788, b)
}

func Benchmark256kEncoder(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkEncoder("testdata/78772815-256k.json", 792, b)
}

The results looked like this:
go test -bench=. -cpu=1,2,4
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: github.com/mwmahlberg/go-unmarshalperformance-78772815
Benchmark64kMapStringInterface              5490            217707 ns/op
Benchmark64kMapStringInterface-2            6572            172025 ns/op
Benchmark64kMapStringInterface-4            6513            176681 ns/op
Benchmark128kMapStringInterface             1321            893114 ns/op
Benchmark128kMapStringInterface-2           1632            707845 ns/op
Benchmark128kMapStringInterface-4           1604            737196 ns/op
Benchmark256kMapStringInterface             1322            901109 ns/op
Benchmark256kMapStringInterface-2           1635            706265 ns/op
Benchmark256kMapStringInterface-4           1606            730651 ns/op
Benchmark64kStruct                         16815             72051 ns/op
Benchmark64kStruct-2                       16618             69919 ns/op
Benchmark64kStruct-4                       16864             70883 ns/op
Benchmark128kStruct                         3979            289447 ns/op
Benchmark128kStruct-2                       4040            280413 ns/op
Benchmark128kStruct-4                       4089            286967 ns/op
Benchmark256kStruct                         4029            283122 ns/op
Benchmark256kStruct-2                       4070            282152 ns/op
Benchmark256kStruct-4                       4094            285352 ns/op
Benchmark64kEncoder                         6207            212767 ns/op
Benchmark64kEncoder-2                       6490            172975 ns/op
Benchmark64kEncoder-4                       6692            174391 ns/op
Benchmark128kEncoder                        1358            867077 ns/op
Benchmark128kEncoder-2                      1651            698896 ns/op
Benchmark128kEncoder-4                      1638            716011 ns/op
Benchmark256kEncoder                        1358            872206 ns/op
Benchmark256kEncoder-2                      1656            706698 ns/op
Benchmark256kEncoder-4                      1647            721699 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/mwmahlberg/go-unmarshalperformance-78772815  36.178s

So, what does this tell us? It tells us that our testdata JSON with a size of 64k was marshaled at least 1321 times per second and more than 16000 times under the optimal circumstances.
If (substantially less) than a millisecond is not sufficiently performant, you should think about horizontal scaling.

@CeriseLimón Uuupps, will correct that.

@CeriseLimón Fixed. Thanks again.

Thanks. As I understand, it means that marshaling structs is more efficient.
The question is how to do marshaling with the least CPU usage.
Btw I profiled the whole service and marshaling consumed 21% of the CPU usage which is a lot.

@dan245 That depends. 21% of available CPU or 21% of the CPU used? ;)

21% of the CPU used.

@dan245 Crazy. I come nowhere near this.
